# Adding Button to LinearLayout programmatically doesn't work properly

Tags: android, android-layout, button, layout-inflater

I have a multiple dimens.xml files for all "smallest width" that I use for button size. And also I have multiple versions for main layout and for button layout (for multi-screen support).

I want to insert multiple buttons into layout programmatically and inflate this button with layout from xml.

This is how I do this:

```
    Button temp_button = null;
    final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
       temp_button = (Button)inflater.inflate(R.layout.answer_letter_button, null);
       temp_button.setTextColor(accent_color);

       answer_letters.add(temp_button);

       answer_panel.addView(answer_letters.get(i));
}
```

This is a parent layout for these buttons:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/answer_panel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/letter_panel">
</LinearLayout>
```

And button layout:

```
<Button
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/answer_letter_button_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/answer_letter_button_size"
    android:text="M"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textSize="@dimen/answer_letter_button_text_size"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/answer_letter_button_margin_size"
    android:background="@drawable/shaped_button" />
```

What I want to see:
[image]

What I actually see:

[image]

What am I doing wrong, somebody tell me?

**Sorry, I incorrectly expressed.**
I mean, that something is wrong with the size of the resulting button. Mostly with a width of a button.

Comment: why you are adding your button view inside **answer_letters** first and then **answer_panel** to?

Comment: you are running a loop here, thats why number of buttons are showing there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add `layout_weight` param and set it to `1` also change `layout_width` and `layout_height` to `wrap_content`,  you can'y add 7 items and set height and width from dimens. Your way will be always wrong and result also. Set only textSize from dimens and it be look what you search for.

```
 <Button
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="M"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="@dimen/answer_letter_button_text_size"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/answer_letter_button_margin_size"
        android:background="@drawable/shaped_button" />
```

And add in your parent layout, `android:weightSum="7"`.

Comment: Sorry, I incorrectly expressed. I mean, that something is wrong with the size of the resulting button. Mostly with a width of a button.